# multiple images in Microdata tags for Facebook catalogues

Tags: facebook, json-ld, facebook-pixel

I am trying to sync my product catalog with my website using json-ld micro-tags and facebook pixel, i managed to sync almost everything but still can't sync more then one image for each product, i tried adding the links as string in the tag "additional_image_link" but no success :(, can anyone help me ?

thins is my current microtags

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "id":"92733",
    "description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
    "productID":"gc-wbax",
    "sku":"gc-wbax",
    "brand":"gc-wbax",
    "name": "Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
    "image_link": "https://example.com/0610061da72519685dbb74c629e0.webp",
    "additional_image_link" : "https://example.com/media/0f478bfd25ce1afef515d42f1274.webp;https://example.com/c73ae46fa96a85e0be20109469cd.webp",
    "offers": {
      "@type": "Offer",
      "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/NewCondition",
      "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
      "highPrice": "1700",
      "lowPrice": "1700",
      "price": "1700",
      "offerCount": "1",
      "priceCurrency": "USD"
    },
    "url": "https://example.com"
  }
</script>
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog/reference says, _“URLs for additional images of the item. Include up to 20 image URLs. Use a comma to separate multiple URLs.”_ - you appear to have used a semicolon instead.

Comment: It also says, _“Since this field takes a string, the entire list of URLs must be formatted with double quotes. For example: `"https://www.fb.com/t_shirt_2.jpg,https://www.fb.com/t_shirt_3.jpg"`”_ - so _could be_, that you need to include those as well (I am not exactly sure what context that is referring to.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the correct property name or syntax for the json-ld/schema.org code you are using.

Multiple images would be entered like this:

"image":[
"https://example.com/0610061da72519685dbb74c629e0.webp",
"https://example.com/media/0f478bfd25ce1afef515d42f1274.webp",
"https://example.com/c73ae46fa96a85e0be20109469cd.webp"
]

It is unclear if Facebook does support multiple images in json-ld/schema.org. You would have to test.